# What is the difference between Math and Maths?

Tags: soft-question

Probably considered an off topic question, but I have only heard math referred to as maths with a plural "s" recently. Why is it maths now? What is wrong with math? Is this just a regional pronunciation or does this refer to specific fields of math? I'm not familiar with this terminology. Just curious.

Comment: Because "maths" is short for "mathematic**s**". It's a consideration that the word we're shortening is plural, so the shortening should be plural also.

Comment: Regional. I am American. I say math. People from other English speaking regions are known to say "maths". Remember, either is short for mathematic***s***.

Comment: That's what I thought. I felt out of the loop or something.

Comment: Oddly enough, I say _stat_ or _stats_ depending on the situation. Like, "He studies stats" as opposed to "I am taking that stat class". I wonder if I am the only one.

Comment: It's purely regional.  Americans say Math and Sports and Brits say Maths and Sport.  One is obvious reasonable and correct and the other is obviously irritatingly wrong and bizarre that those other people keep insisting on saying the weird thing.

Comment: The difference between American and English ;o)

Comment: I wish there was a way to register a don't-close vote. The question was closeable until that Answer appeared - the answer needs to be preserved for posterity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is clearly the letter s. In truth it is simply a matter of convention that should be asked somewhere like here https://ell.stackexchange.com/ for more details.

Comment: I can delete the question here, which I probably will. I just wanted to know if it referred to something specific, which would be a valid question.

Comment: Understandable, I just didn't want to leave you without other resources to turn to if answers here didn't give enough clarity.

Comment: The whole thing should stay up! "The answer is clearly the letter s" is simply brilliant.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich  lol, agreed.